# VBA HTTP POST not working

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to send HTTP post through VBA. Here is my part of code

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHTTP.Open "POST", url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "EPS 1.0"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "content", postString
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(postString)
objHTTP.send
```

The problem is, the code is working only if the `postString` is less than `65535` characters. If it exceeds `65535` characters, it throws error on below line:

> ERROR: Incorrect parameter

```
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "content", postString
```

Any ideas about this? Do I need to set any other parameter to make it work around?

Comment: What happens if you send your postString via `send`? So, comment out `objHTTP.setRequestHeader "content", postString` and amend `objHTTP.send postString`

Comment: @TEK I've tried and received no errors. But the response is failure meaning that the server didn't received any content

Comment: The reason is the server accepts only the contents posted through header. This is why I am sending via header

Comment: Odd that the server only accepts content up to 16 bits. Have you posted anything else to this server through different means to verify it can accept content greater than 16 bits?

Comment: Yes. It is working well when I post it through PERL and PHP

Comment: Humour me for one more minute, then I'll go away and think about it. Can you change the creation string from `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` to `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` and let me know what happens.

Comment: I'd tried that already but not worked

Comment: Its extremely odd to pass 65k as an HTTP **Header** value, that's way in advance of apache/iis default limits on request size - are you sure `postString` is not meant to be a *post string*? I.e the content of the request *body* as opposed to a header?

Comment: ```Content``` header? Shouldn't it be just ```objHTTP.send(postString)```? [Here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) is no ```Content``` header specified.

Comment: @AlexK. what do you mean?

Comment: @dee I already mentioned that, I'd tried `objHTTP.send(postString)` but I didn't receive any information on the server side

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4

Comment: "The reason is the server accepts only the contents posted through header. This is why I am sending via header"  - that is the OPPOSITE of POST, which as others have pointed out, expects the data to be in the BODY of the request.  HTTP headers do have a limit on size - varies according to exact platform but see (eg) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097651/is-there-a-practical-http-header-length-limit

Comment: @TimWilliams I agree but even when I'm sending through post, the same problem exists. The question is about how to pass the data which is more than 65535 characters, not about header or post

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? The cutoff limit sounds too familiar (Excel 2003 has a max rows limit of 65,536)

Comment: 1) You said the POST worked through PHP. Can you post the PHP code here? 2) Can you add this code at the top of this function and give us the output:    `MessageBox len(poststring)`

Comment: Still not getting it done

Comment: change the user agent to ie

Comment: why? whats wrong with this

Comment: The address bar doesn’t shows any characters beyond 65,536 characters.but opera browser  URL is completely visible in the address bar even at such a big range

Comment: so try to add opera as a user agent...

Answer (score 3):

Per: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290591

This *should work*:

```
postString = "id=" & String(66000,"x")
Dim xmlhttp 
Set xmlhttp = Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST", url, false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.send postString
```

If it does *not* work, then maybe there's something going on with your server-side setup.

Comment: Can you explain `"id=" & String(66000,"x")`

Comment: That was just a dummy data string to pass for testing: a parameter named "id" with a 66k character value.

Comment: Same problem.. The server didn't received anything via post. If it is <65535, i saw the post data in server. And also, the received full data when I was checking this in perl and php. So clearly, this is an VBA issue

Comment: If you monitor the request using something like Fiddler, what do you see?

Comment: And it might be useful to say something about your server platform - what are you using?