# What's the Max Request URI Length in Tomcat and How to configure it?

Tags: spring, apache, spring-boot, tomcat

What is the max request URI length configured in `Apache-Tomcat` that's embedded in a `spring-boot` application? Also, How do I configure it?

I looked into many places and found `maxHttpHeaderSize`, but that is the max size of the headers, of both `request` and `response`, and not just the `URI`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a practical HTTP Header length limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097651/is-there-a-practical-http-header-length-limit)

Comment: The answers are in the question I posted above.