# Asp.net core identity custom token provider TokenLifeSpan does not work when hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I have an asp.net core 3.1 MVC project with IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity 3.1.2. When a user has created, an email with a link including confirming email token is sent using worker service to the user's email address. (Note - token is created from asp.net core MVC project, only the email sending part is handled with the worker service)

A custom email confirmation token provider is used to generate the token with the TokenLifeSpan of 1 day and other default DataProtectionTokenProviders' TokenLifeSpans are set to 2 hours.
When asp.net core MVC application is hosted in **IIS**, the token expires before the specified token life span (expires before 1 hour). But, when the visual studio, **Project** option is selected in the **Launch** section (launches with Kestrel) token life span duration works properly.

The code used for registering custom token providers and life spans are mentioned below.

```
          {
              
              options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
              options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
              options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
              options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
              options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
              options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "CustomEmailConfirmation";
              options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = config.GetValue<int>("IdentityServerConfigurations:MaxFailedAccessAttempts");

          })
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
          .AddTokenProvider<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>>("CustomEmailConfirmation");

        
          services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(opt =>
             opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2));

          services.Configure<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions>(opt =>
          opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Are you running HTTPS in IIS as well?

Comment: Yes I do use HTTPS

Comment: another problem with IIS is that it might be sensitive with too large headers/cookies

Comment: @ToreNestenius can you please provide more information on how large headers/cookies would affect this.

Comment: Because IIS might be configured to reject to large requests and in ASP.NET Core, the cookeis can be quite large when you also store the tokens inside it. so its a potential error  source .... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097651/is-there-a-practical-http-header-length-limit

Comment: @ToreNestenius thanks for your reply. But in my scenario, I use query string parameters and the URL is less than 2048 characters. There are no limits set for request filtering and cookies, using default values of iis. The example of the URL is ```https://localhost/IdentityServer/Account/ResetPassword?token=Q2ZESjhQMitzU2RsQlNCSm5XTVNtRVFIOUg2aDRGWFlOdG4rZjY5RjU4a2hRc&email=abc@gmail.com&returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard-landing&InitialPasswordSet=True ```

Comment: There is no redeployment of the IIS service when it fails?