# X-Forwarded-For (XFF) HTTP header

Tags: http-headers

How many characters can the value of the X-Forwarded-For (XFF) HTTP header value be?

Example is: 
    X-Forwarded-For: client1, proxy1, proxy2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no limit. Note that you shouldn't rely on its value; it can be [spoofed easily](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-SE/firefox/addon/5948/). (Note however that if you're using a load-balancing proxy that overwrites this value, you *can* rely on it as you're setting it yourself)

Comment: But if all of your connections are coming in through your load balancer (or other proxy), and you do not allow the world to connect to your bare back-end server's 80 and 443, then you can rely on the header since good load balancers always overwrite whatever made-up value a user might try to provide with a real one computed from the client IP address.

Comment: @Brandon: Well yes, if you're controlling its value using a load-balancing proxy you can rely on it.

Comment: Add that tidbit to your answer — so users don't think that X-Forwarded-For is always and in all circumstances spoofable, and I'll be happy to +1 your answer — thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097651/is-there-a-practical-http-header-length-limit), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654921/how-big-can-a-user-agent-string-get) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values) (related SO questions).

The spec does not specify a limit (so, unlimited, in theory). However, there is a limit that is implementation specific.

[IIS 6/7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260694) allow up to 16K per header, apache will [default to 8K](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize).