# Is there a site which shows peoples User-Agent without cutting off long ones?

Tags: asp.net, http-headers, user-agent, browser-detection

Basically, I know of this website http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com but it truncates the user-agents it gathers to 150 chrs.

I also know of http://botsvsbrowsers.com but that site (although better) truncates to 200 chrs.

I just want a website similar to these ones (any site that shows other users user-agents) but allows for at least 300 chrs or does not truncate them!

Also, if you don't know weather the site you have in mind truncates the User-Agent, that's ok. As long as it's a site that lists the user-agents of people that visit it or user-agents gathered from some real-time source, that is more than appropriate, just list the site as an answer or comment and I will go do the checking to see if it shows the full User-Agent or to find out how many chrs it allows for. After I do this, I will let everyone know the results in a comment :).

.

*Unnecessary Additional Reading (Why I Asked This Question):*

Basically I need this to gather a large sample of user-agents (does not need to be representative of any particular audience) and having user-agents where they are abruptly cutoff contaminates and corrupts my sample. This sample I am collecting is for research.

Answer (score 2):

Try [UserAgentString.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php), it will display and analyze your full user agent string, and it has a very large database of sample UA strings for all sorts of browsers and other agents. I saw some sample IE 8 user agent strings on there that were 227+ characters in length, not cut off.

Comment: I just found this without the quotes, cut off at exactly 250 chrs: "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3; .NET4.0C; .NE" so was cut off right before .NE could spell .NET. Still a good find though. Up voted.

Comment: I did find these guys, http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/ who have a download names "known agents.zip" who has a list of all user agents, uncut, since 1997 or something lol. i downloaded and had a look. also, it is unique agents, so doubles removed so that you can't get a representative sample because they are just uniques. maybe i should look into how user-agents are put together and search for sub-user-agent strings (ie: product strings inside the UA's)....

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [detectmobilebrowsers.com/](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) also shows value of user-agent without cutting down.

Comment: https://user-agents.top is also showing full value