# What can be the maximum length of HTTP_USER_AGENT?

Tags: php, sql

I am storing `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` of a client in database. What is the recommended length that I could give to `varchar(length)` for `HTTP_USER_AGENT`?

[this website](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) shows value of `HTTP_USER_AGENT`. I visited from my PC, and the value is 109 characters long. From this I was planning to give varchar(150), but I want to confirm what can be the maximum value of `HTTP_USER_AGENT`. I don't want to give too long length to my varchar.

Comment: I don't know why you even mention varchar. You should have just left your question containing *"what can be the maximum value of HTTP_USER_AGENT"*. I don't see relevance here or why it would even matter.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654921/how-big-can-a-user-agent-string-get

Comment: I'd just use `TEXT` for it. The user agent is quite quirky in some browsers, and if you really want to ensure you're getting the whole thing, then don't limit it at all.

Comment: May be you can encrypt it and store

Comment: @n01ze How does encryption help here?!

Comment: atleast it will reduce the size ... just saying , workaround

Comment: @n01ze How does encryption reduce size?!

Comment: *"I'd just use `TEXT` for it."* @deceze which was an answer given http://stackoverflow.com/a/13506920/ in the duplicate I found the question to be. *Bad call on my part?*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Even if the answer happens to be extremely similar, the question was indeed very different as were the reasons for arriving at the answer. "I'm worried about the maximum row length and how to store long values in it" vs. "how much should I set aside for a particular type of value..."

Comment: You could use varchar(255) if you dont care about truncation.  It depends why you are saving the data.  Is it just for logging, or do you really need to store every byte?

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the added explanation. - and Elyor: Sorry about that, I made a mistake. After all, *I'm only human* ;-)