# Laravel Altek Accountant causes database errors with user_agent

Tags: laravel

I'm new to using Laravel. I'm working on a friend's project that uses https://packagist.org/packages/altek/accountants

We released the project into production, but we notice database errors like this:

```
SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'user_agent' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `ledgers` (`user_id`, `user_type`, `context`, `event`, `recordable_id`, `recordable_type`, `properties`, `modified`, `extra`, `url`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `pivot`, `signature`) values (?, ?, 4, created, 28, App\User, {"email":"johnceo@johnceo.com","password":"blah","accept_terms":true,"updated_at":"2020-11-02 14:35:38","created_at":"2020-11-02 14:35:38","id":28}, ["email","password","accept_terms","updated_at","created_at","id"], [], https://example.com/auth/register, 172.1.1.1, Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 LightSpeed [FBAN/MessengerLiteForiOS;FBAV/288.0.0.39.118;FBBV/252761750;FBDV/iPhone12,3;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iOS;FBSV/13.6;FBSS/3;FBCR/;FBID/phone;FBLC/en;FBOP/0], 2020-11-02 14:35:38, 2020-11-02 14:35:38, [], 10dijfjajj3iasdio335ef37438126ed3b6ab307c996670b24ab28d6a6004f8dd00198208c46899439378321629941dae14edda681ce8235ef349343e940f4a32746aab6e00d1fe9a))
```

This question here says we should prepare for insanely long user agents: [How big can a user agent string get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654921/how-big-can-a-user-agent-string-get)

Is there a idiomatic way to address this issue in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the package documentation
[here](https://altek.gitlab.io/accountant/ledger-table.html#values-with-more-than-255-characters)

> While odd, on some occasions, User Agent values may go over the 255 character mark. To avoid insertion problems, update the column from
> $table->string('user_agent')->nullable();
> to
> $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();