# Cannot create a row of size 8064 which is greater than the allowable row size of 8060

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've have this strange problem when adding a column to an existing table.

The existing table looks like :

```
CREATE TABLE [BinaryAssets].[BinaryAssets](
 [BinaryAssetId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [BinaryAssetStructureId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 [Created_By] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Created_On] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 [Modified_By] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Modified_On] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BinaryAsset] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
 [BinaryAssetId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now, the sql I'm trying to execute looks like :

```
ALTER TABLE BinaryAssets.BinaryAssets ADD
 [Version] INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_BinaryAssets_Version DEFAULT 1

ALTER TABLE BinaryAssets.BinaryAssets
 DROP CONSTRAINT DF_BinaryAssets_Version
```

When I'm trying to execute I get a sqlexception (see Title).

Now, I don't think my table exceeds 8060, so what's the problem here. Strange thing is that when I change for instance the Name from nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(100), then execute my new sql and then change back the 100 to MAX, it does work... logic seems far away here.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: what are you putting in [Name] that requires nvarchar(max) ? Can't you just use nvarchar(100)?

Comment: I understand the answers telling you the 8,000 size is the maximum for a record. But how is that you can resize it to max, later... This is only a (very crazy) guess: maybe max is indicating "use all the available space" and when you create it, sqlserver is reserving the available space so far (before getting into account the rest of the fields). So, you could try to create the table with the [Name] field in the last position, to see what happens :) (just for fun)

Comment: Mmm, indeed, that could be it, but I would still find it strange.

Comment: Can you edit the post / tags to indicate SQL 7/2000/2005/2008 since the answers being given for SQL 2000/7 would be totally incorrect if it is 2005/2008

Comment: I've tried replicating this to no avail - even if I specifically prime the page and check prior to the alter command (using dbcc ind / dbcc page to check I am at the limits) I can not get it to throw the error. Is there something else you have omitted or some simplification you've applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest size you can give an `nvarchar` field is of `MAX`, wich is 4000 chars (2 bytes Unicode chars).

> [In SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 7](http://www.teratrax.com/articles/varchar_max.html), a
>   row cannot exceed 8000 bytes in size.
>   This means that a `VARBINARY` column can
>   only store 8000 bytes (assuming it is
>   the only column in a table), a `VARCHAR`
>   column can store up to 8000 characters
>   and an `NVARCHAR` column can store up to
>   4000 characters (2 bytes per unicode
>   character). This limitation stems from
>   the 8 KB internal page size SQL Server
>   uses to save data to disk.

If you need to store a longer body of text, you should be using either [`text`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564755/sql-server-text-type-v-s-varchar-data-type) or `ntext`, which can hold as much text as your system has hard drive space.

You seem to be trying to create a row with a size *larger* than the possible size, which is not a valid operation.

Comment: The maximum for a 2005/2008 nvarchar is 4000 when specified as a specific number, but when using the nvarchar(max) keyword you have 2^31-1 bytes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Set the `sp_tableoption` stored procedure `'large value types out of row'` option to ON to store the field off page.

Comment: He should be using a text field if he is working with that amount of text anyway.

Comment: Why should the poster be using a TEXT data type? They are to be deprecated and have been replcaced with nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max). See SQL Server Books Online: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2005/2008, the page size is the same (8K), but the database uses pointers on the row in the page to point to other pages that contain larger fields. This allows 2005 to overcome the 8K row size limitation.