# LINQ Large string (64k) not inserted into SQL Database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, varcharmax

I have a column in SQL varchar(max). Using LINQ, when I'm trying to add a record with a string over 64k large, the value is not saved into DB. I'm simply doing;

```
test.MyString = LargeString; //(over 64k text)
mydb.myTable.InsertOnSubmit(test);
mydb.SubmitChanges();
```

Is there a limit when using LINQ to SQL ?  What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Are you getting some exception? Or just the column turns out empty? What happens if you assign a smaller string like "test string"?

Comment: Was the size of the field just recently increased to MAX?  If so, you may need to recompile the DBML

Comment: I'm not getting any exception, and te column turns empty (not NULL) No problem with smaller string. I also removed the table from my DBML et readded the table. Same problem.

Comment: I finally upgraded from SQL 2005 to SQL 2008 R2. Now it's working, but I have no idea why this was not working under SQL 2005.

Answer (score 8):

[`VarChar(Max)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) supports string of upto 8000 characters (SQL Server 2k). On 2005+ this should not cause error.

You may want to use `Text` fields; [for SQL Server 2005+, `VarChar(Max)` is preferred](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).

> **Important**
>
> ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a
>   future version of MicrosoftSQL Server. Avoid using these data types in
>   new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently
>   use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.
>   Fixed and variable-length data types for storing large non-Unicode and
>   Unicode character and binary data. Unicode data uses the UNICODE UCS-2
>   character set.

See this for details on VarChar & Text data type

1. [SQL Server Text type vs. varchar data type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/564755/277290)
2. [MSDN: ntext, text, and image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276838%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

---

I noticed you are calling `InsertOnSubmit` on `mydb` and calling `SubmitChanges` on `ISNetDB` - is this typo or cause of the error.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Should be mydb.SubmitChanges