# Delete a row from a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, delete-row

I'm trying to simply delete a full row from my SQL Server database table using a button event. So far none of my attempts have succeeded. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
public static void deleteRow(string table, string columnName, string IDNumber)
{
    try
    {
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Global.connectionString))
    {
         con.Open();
         using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE " + columnName + " = " + IDNumber, con))
         {
               command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         con.Close();
    }
    }
    catch (SystemException ex)
       {
       MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message));
       }
    }
}
```

I keep receiving the error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   An error occurred: Operand type clash: text is incompatible with int

All of the columns in the table are of `TEXT` type. Why cannot I compare the function argument of type `string` to the columns to find the match? (And then delete the row?)

Comment: You should be using parameters for this.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use parameters, any examples? Resources?

Comment: Also, as a side-note: first of all, you shouldn't use `TEXT` anymore - as of SQL Server 2005 it's deprecated. Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead. Also: having **all columns** be `VARCHAR(MAX)` smells like a terrible design - do you **REALLY** need 2 GB of text for **each column**?? **REALLY!?!?!?** Design and performance tip: use appropriate data types

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you have stated that all column names are of TEXT type, So, there is need to use IDNumber as Text by using single quote around IDNumber.....

```
    public static void deleteRow(string table, string columnName, string IDNumber)
    {
    try
    {
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Global.connectionString))
    {
         con.Open();
         using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE " + columnName + " = '" + IDNumber+"'", con))
         {
               command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         con.Close();
    }
    }
    catch (SystemException ex)
       {
       MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message));
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should ALWAYS use parameterised queries for this type of operation.

Answer (score 6):

Either `IDNumber` should be an `int` instead of a `string`, or if it's really a `string`, add quotes.

Better yet, use parameters.

Comment: using regular quotes (") i get this back: `An error occurred: Invalid column name '50012'.` where 50012 was the IDNumber (string).

Comment: @ikathegreat - try kashif's example. Using parameters avoids the hassle of mucking with data types like this. Also, as other posters said, you almost certainly don't want all of these fields to be TEXT.

Answer (score 5):

Try with paramter

```
.....................
.....................

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE " + columnName + " = " + @IDNumber, con))
             {
                   command.Paramter.Add("@IDNumber",IDNumber)
                   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }

.....................
.....................
```

**No need to close connection in using statement**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like IDNumber is a string.  It needs single quote wrapped around it.

```
"DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE " + columnName + " = '" + IDNumber + "'"
```

Comment: this returns: `An error occurred: The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.`

Answer (score 1):

You may change the "columnName" type from `TEXT` to `VARCHAR(MAX). TEXT` column can't be used with `"="`.
[see this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564755/sql-server-text-type-vs-varchar-data-type)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String st = "DELETE FROM supplier WHERE supplier_id =" + textBox1.Text;

    SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(st, myConnection);
    try
    {
        sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("delete successful");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}



private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String st = "SELECT * FROM suppliers";

    SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(st, myConnection);
    try
    {
        sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader reader = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        datatable.Load(reader);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql Wamp. This code work.

```
string con="SERVER=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=dbname";
public void delete()
{
try
{
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(con);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
connect.Open();
da.DeleteCommand = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM table WHERE ID='" + ID.Text + "'", connect);
da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("Successfully Deleted");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void DeleteProductButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string ProductID = deleteProductButton.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductID))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid ProductID");
        deleteProductButton.Focus();
    }
    try
    {
        string SelectDelete = "Delete from Products where ProductID=" + deleteProductButton.Text;
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SelectDelete, Conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandTimeout = 15;

        DialogResult comfirmDelete = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
        if (comfirmDelete == DialogResult.No)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);

    }
}
```

Comment: What does your answer improve upon the accepted answer on this 7 year old question?