# Store SQL inside SQL

Tags: sql

I want to store SQL statements inside SQL db. What datatype would you recommend for that?

At the moment I am using varchar(max), is it OK?

Also I do have a problem, probably because of the brackets, it tells me:
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'.`

Do you have any example how should I execute query to avoid such error?

Thanks

Comment: You'd probably be better off with `nvarchar(max)`, since that will permit you to have characters not in ASCII.

Comment: Have you considered using stored procedures for this?

Comment: Yes, varchar(max) is OK. But no one will be able to help you with your error without the specific code you are using.

Comment: Marek, how do I escape them? What do you mean? I need them for valid query.

Comment: Possible duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564755/sql-server-text-type-vs-varchar-data-type. And you should escape the query, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its better you make use of `nvarchar(max)` and escape **`'`** in you sql statement replace by **`''`** so it doesnt cause any problem for you

Comment: @WildGoat That what I meant by [escaping the quote characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).