# Using SqlReader, when using reader.GetString(1) -OR- reader["Details"], it only retrieves 4000 bytes of the string. How do I get the rest?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have instantiated an SqlDataReader, and when using reader.GetString(1)  -OR- reader["Details"], it only retrieves the first 4000 characters of the string.  How do I get the rest?

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
try
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string foo = reader["Name"];
        string bar = reader.GetString(1);    //reader["Details"];
        // bar ONLY has the first 4000 bytes - not the entire field!
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the length of the field in the database table definition?

Comment: Why are you saying "bytes"? `varchar/nvarchar` columns and strings are measured in Characters, not Bytes. And a Character is not necessarily a single byte (though assuming UTF-16, it's 2 or 4 bytes per character).

Comment: Also, it's `SqlDataReader`, not `SqlReader` - unless you're using some other library?

Comment: I said "bytes" because I write the results to a file, and the file has a size, which is measured in bytes.  I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Details column in your database typed as text or ntext? If so, you need to use a method similar to that for blob data:

[How to read and write a file to and from a BLOB column by using chunking in ADO.NET and Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317043/how-to-read-and-write-a-file-to-and-from-a-blob-column-by-using-chunki)

It's worth noting that TEXT and NTEXT are being deprecated. nvarchar and varchar are likely the types you are looking for.

see: [SQL Server Text type vs. varchar data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564755/sql-server-text-type-vs-varchar-data-type)