# Which data type should I use for optional string in mysql?

Tags: mysql, text, varchar

I am trying to decide which mysql variable type should I use when i want to store a string which is optional and mostly it would be null.
I am thinking of using **BLOB** or **TEXT** like variable instead of varchar here are my supporting reasons:

1. I want the optional string to have more length within 64 kb.I don't want data truncation.
2. TEXT variables does not have data padding in normal case and this are pretty compact for short tests.
3. Knowing these type of data are allocated in area out of the table area  and has a overhead while retrieving, I am ready to accept this little overhead; since I will be using it less often.

example would be:

```
      column_a | column_b| column_c| column_d| optional_column
---------------+---------+---------+---------+-----------------
asdfasdf       |asdfasdf |sdfsdfas |dadasd   |NULL
asdfasdf       |asdfasdf |sdfsdfas |dadasd   |NULL
asdfasdf       |asdfasdf |sdfsdfas |dadasd   |as,fgdfg
asdfasdf       |asdfasdf |sdfsdfas |dadasd   |NULL
asdfasdf       |asdfasdf |sdfsdfas |dadasd   |NULL
asdfasdf       |asdfasdf |sdfsdfas |dadasd   |asd,asda
asdfasdf       |asdfasdf |sdfsdfas |dadasd   |NULL
asdfasdf       |asdfasdf |sdfsdfas |dadasd   |NULL
asdfasdf       |asdfasdf |sdfsdfas |dadasd   |NULL
asdfasdf       |asdfasdf |sdfsdfas |dadasd   |NULL
asdfasdf       |asdfasdf |sdfsdfas |dadasd   |{"asdasd":"Asdas"....
```

Please suggest me according to my situation.
fyi I am thinking of using TEXT. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you  want to store different datatypes in it especially json I would store an key from an different table. Inside that table I would store every accepted type in a column. This leads to some more null values but it gives also huge advantages for searching, filtering and so on. If you just want to store text, than use text not blob.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a TEXT field because text is what you store in it. BLOB fields should be used to store binary data like images.
Both field types are searchable, if that is needed too. So its more likely a design decision. I prefer using the type for what it is supposed to store.

Comment: Thanks the response, btw I aware  of  this :).

Comment: @PreetamKumar if you were aware the above, then why did you ask the question in the first place?

Comment: @Shadow I did not mentioned of using BLOB , I mentioned TEXT and BLOB like datatype (fyi I am clear about using TEXT ). So I would like suggestions according to my situation.

Comment: @PreetamKumar You have one data type that is gear towards storing text, and another one that is not. And you want to store text. Is it truly such a difficult question to decide which of the 2 to use? Btw you ruled out varchar with the length requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`TEXT` is used for large pieces of string data. If the length of the field exceeed a certain threshold, the text is stored out of row.

`VARCHAR` is always stored in row and has a limit of *8000* characters. If you try to create a `VARCHAR(x)`, where *x > 8000*, you get an error:

> Server: Msg 131, Level 15, State 3, Line 1
>
> The size () given to the type ‘varchar’ exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000)

These length limitations do not concern `VARCHAR(MAX)` in *SQL Server 2005*, which may be stored out of row, just like `TEXT`.

Note that `MAX` is not a kind of constant here, `VARCHAR` and `VARCHAR(MAX)` are very different types, the latter being very close to `TEXT`.

In prior versions of *SQL Server* you could not access the `TEXT` directly, you only could get a `TEXTPTR` and use it in `READTEXT` and `WRITETEXT` functions.

In *SQL Server 2005* you can directly access `TEXT` columns (though you still need an explicit cast to `VARCHAR` to assign a value for them).

`TEXT` is good:

- If you need to store large texts in your database
- If you do not search on the value of the column
- If you select this column rarely and do not join on it.

`VARCHAR` is good:

- If you store little strings
- If you search on the string value
- If you always select it or use it in joins.

By *selecting* here I mean issuing any queries that return the value of the column.

By *searching* here I mean issuing any queries whose result depends on the value of the `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` column. This includes using it in any `JOIN` or `WHERE` condition.

As the `TEXT` is stored out of row, the queries not involving the `TEXT` column are usually faster.

Some examples of what `TEXT` is good for:

- Blog comments
- Wiki pages
- Code source

Some examples of what `VARCHAR` is good for:

- Usernames
- Page titles
- Filenames

As a rule of thumb, if you ever need you text value to exceed *200* characters **AND** do not use join on this column, use `TEXT`.

Otherwise use `VARCHAR`.

*P.S.* The same applies to `UNICODE` enabled `NTEXT` and `NVARCHAR` as well, which you should use for examples above.

*P.P.S.* The same applies to `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)` that *SQL Server 2005+* uses instead of `TEXT` and `NTEXT`. You'll need to enable `large value types out of row` for them with `sp_tableoption` if you want them to be always stored out of row.

As mentioned above and [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189087.aspx), `TEXT` is going to be deprecated in future releases:

> The `text in row` option will be removed in a future version of *SQL Server*. Avoid using this option in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use `text in row`. We recommend that you store large data by using the `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)`, or `varbinary(max)` data types. To control in-row and out-of-row behavior of these data types, use the `large value types out of row` option.

**Copied from [SQL Server Text type vs. varchar data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564755/sql-server-text-type-vs-varchar-data-type)**

Comment: For this reason, i recommend to use `Text` as variable type

Comment: Nice answer. There is just one little glitch: the question is about mysql and not ms sql server.

Comment: @SacrumDeus thanks for the answer it is elaborative. I can see you are expressing in context to Microsoft SQL server. If you can assure me in context of MySQL it would really help.

Comment: @SacrumDeus Of Course, I appreciate it, It is a hint I agree with, I am looking for answer specific to Mysql with reasons.  :)