# Column data truncation in TEXT to NVARCHAR(max) data type conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

The older data types text, `Ntext` and `image` are deprecated and while converting some columns to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARCHAR(max)`, the data is getting truncated.  There's no alternate provided anywhere and I needed some help.

Comment: Are the data being truncated to a particular size/length?

Comment: You need to convert `NTEXT` -> `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, `TEXT` -> `VARCHAR(MAX)`, and `IMAGE` -> `VARBINARY(MAX)`. You're not mentioning `varbinary(max)` in your question - so what are you converting your `image` columns to?? You cannot convert those to a string-based datatype like `(n)varchar(max)`, of course!

Comment: Here the question is about the size and data truncation. of course image should be converted into VARBINARY(max). And I am trying to convert TEXT -> VARCHAR(max).

Comment: Please share your code for the convert.

Comment: ALTER TABLE <tableName>  ALTER COLUMN <ColumnName of TEXT data type> VARCHAR(max)

Comment: Hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564755/sql-server-text-type-vs-varchar-data-type/564823

Comment: Check `DATALENGTH` before and after to check if the data is actually getting truncated, or it's an artifact of getting/displaying it. You may also wish to check the result of a `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ...)` to see if there are icky things like NUL characters that might gum up the works (I think those should just get copied without change, but there are scenarios where SQL Server really doesn't like them in strings).

Comment: You may also wish to double check that the column's current collation is what you expect it to be, and that it matches the database default. If not, specify a `COLLATE` clause explicitly in the `ALTER`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I found it as an problem in displaying the data while before and after conversion DATALENGTH remains the same. Thank You