# Column of "text" type shown incorrectly in MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

In MSSQL DB I have column ResponseInfo of type (text, null).
For some (!) rows MS SQL Management Studio shows incorrect output for the column.

For value (expected result):

```
{"result":"Status:U-OK","hasError":false,"errorDetails":null}
```

it shows just only first bracket in Management Studio:

```
{
```

And on "Save Result As" it saves the column value in text file, where every character separated with space:

```
{ " r e s u l t " : " S t a t u s :   U   -   O K " , " h a s E r r o r " : f a l s e , " e r r o r D e t a i l s " : n u l l }
```

I suspect it may relate to encoding (the table encoding is "Latin1_General_100_BIN"), I've tried to create nvarchar(MAX) column and SET the value from ResponseInfo column there, but it outputs for new column the same result.
Please help if you know how to fix this issue.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2005 or later, use varchar(MAX). The text datatype is deprecated and should not be used for new development work. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564755/sql-server-text-type-vs-varchar-data-type

Comment: Assign the value to a variable and use `PRINT (@Variable)`, see if in the message tab the content is being displayed correctly.

Comment: Maybe you should add more details how you save this text

Comment: SSMS is a *management* tool. It won't display an entire 2GB text field, nor will it retain whitespace in the grid. This has nothing to do with encoding. The spaces (NULs really) though suggest you tried to store Unicode text in a `varchar` field instead of `nvarchar`. Change the type to `nvarchar`. The collation doesn't matter, the data type is wrong

Comment: Simply changing the type won't fix the spaces though - those are part of the text now. When SQL Server tries to convert from ASCII to UTF16 it will see the NULs as separate characters. The data should be stored again, or a script should be created to remove NULs (ie `0x00` ) from the string before the conversion.

Comment: Thank you guys, you all correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptoms look like the value for the problem rows was encoded as Unicode when inserted into the database by the application. T-SQL example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable(ResponseInfo text);

DECLARE @UnicodeValue nvarchar(MAX) = N'{"result":"Status:U-OK","hasError":false,"errorDetails":null}';
DECLARE @BinaryValue varbinary(MAX) = CAST(@UnicodeValue AS varbinary(MAX));
DECLARE @VarcharValue varchar(MAX) = CAST(@BinaryValue AS varchar(MAX));

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable VALUES(@VarcharValue);

SELECT ResponseInfo
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

You can check the raw value to verify:

```
SELECT CAST(ResponseInfo AS varbinary(MAX))
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

If the data was not encoded properly, you might be able to reverse the mistake using an update query like the one below. Make sure only the problem rows are targeted.

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET ResponseInfo = CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST(ResponseInfo AS varchar(MAX)) AS varbinary(MAX)) AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS varchar(MAX))
WHERE <problem-row-criteria-here>;
```

Of course, you'll need to fix the application to avoid the problem going forward. Although unrelated to your problem, it would be best to use `varchar(MAX)` or `nvarchar(MAX)` instead of the deprecated `text` data type.

Comment: Thank you Dan, all points you mentioned are about my case. And I even tried you converting script for invalid data - it started showing correct results for me.